# How to store data in python with number of row limit

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

For a project I have devices who send payloads and I should store them on a localfile, but I have memory limitation and I dont want to store more than 2000 data rows. again for the memory limitation I cannot have a database so I chose to store data in csv file.
I tried to use `open('output.csv', 'r+') as f:` ; I'm appending the rows to the end of my csv and I have to check each time the lenght with `sum(1 for line in f)` to be sure its not more than 2000.
The big problem starts when I reach 2000 rows and I want to ideally delete the first row and add another row to the end or start to write rows from the beginning of the file and overwrite the old rows without deleting evrything, but I dont know how to do it. I tried to use `open('output.csv', 'w+')` or `open('output.csv', 'a+')` but it will delete all the contents with w+ while writing only one row and by a+ it just continues to append to the end.  I on the otherhand I cannot count the number of rows anymore with both. can you pleas help me which command should I use to start to rewrite each line from the beginning or delete one line from the beginning and append one to the end? I will also appriciate if you can tell me if there is a better chioce than csv files for storing many data or I can use a better way to count the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. See comments inline

```
import pandas as pd

allowed_length = 2 # Set it to the required value
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv') #Read your csv file to df

row_count = df.shape[0] #Get row count

df.loc[row_count] = ['Fridge', 15] #Insert row at end of df. In my case it has only 2 values

#if count of dataframe is greater or equal to allowed_length, the delete first row
if row_count >= allowed_length:
    df = df.drop(df.head(1).index)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear! but to read the whole data each time to a dataframe and write them back doesn't take too much time?

Comment: It depends on how much data you have.